# Greasemonkey - Browser redirect

Tags: greasemonkey

So it's been a minute since I've used Greasemonkey scripts and I'm probably forgetting to do something basic but...

What I want to do is when ever I navigate to https://beta.crunchyroll.com to instead redirect me to https://beta.crunchyroll.com/simulcasts/seasons/spring-2021 and I think my current code should do that but isn't for some reason.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Crunchyroll Redirect
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include     http://*.crunchyroll.*/*
// @include     https://*.crunchyroll.*/*
// ==/UserScript==

var current_location = content.document.location;

if(current_location == "https://beta.crunchyroll.com"){
            window.location.replace("https://beta.crunchyroll.com/simulcasts/seasons/spring-2021")
}
```

So where did I mess up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the logic.

1. Since you only need to run it on `https://beta.crunchyroll.com`, there is no point on running it on other pages
2. `@match` is more robust than `@include`
3. Use `@run-at` to run at the earliest possible

Here is an example:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Crunchyroll Redirect
// @match         *://beta.crunchyroll.com/*
// @version       1
// @grant         none
// @run-at        document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.stop();    // stop loading
location.replace('https://beta.crunchyroll.com/simulcasts/seasons/spring-2021');
```